# How to eject a disk from a Macbook when it is being used as the boot Disk?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, boot

I'm afraid my hard drive is probably shot, so I was trying to access disk utility via the original install disk, but now I want to eject the disk, but the only way the computer starts up into a usable state is from the the install disk. I want to try some other trouble shooting measures, that aren't via the disc so I need to eject it (or force the computer to not start up from the disk.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100402084809AAhEsvw)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot eject the startup disk, since it is in use.

If your MacBook is a new enough model (one released after OS X 10.7 Lion) or has had its firmware updated since then, it can boot into [Internet Recovery mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718). Essentially, this will boot it from a disk image served over the internet. To invoke it, power the MacBook on, then immediately hold down Command-Option-R until you see a globe in the middle of the screen. That'll leave the disc drive free for other uses.

Comment: you could also clone the startup-Disc onto a FireWire- or USB-drive and then boot from that one.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is a mid 2009, so I guess it is off to the apple store I go.

Comment: Another possibility: Apple used to sell Lion installers in USB key form. I don't think you can still get them from Apple, but they're consistently available on ebay (for around $50). Booting from the installer gets you a minimal OS X environment, very similar to recovery mode: no Finder, but Disk Utility and Terminal are there, and you can actually launch regular apps via the `open` command in Terminal.